# Adding new language to spaCy: lemma lookup problem

Tags: spacy

I'm writing a new  spacy language class for ancient Greek (grc) and it is working at the tokenizer level but fails to do the lemma lookup in a dictionary I built from a corpus. When I run the test for the lookup table with python -m pytest spacy_lookups_data in the corresponding directory of spacy_lookups_data and with a test file I wrote, I get the following error:

grc_nlp = <spacy.lang.grc.AncientGreek object at 0x7fe8a8696730>, string = 'μοι', lemma = ' ἐγώ'

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "string,lemma",
    [
        ("ἄνδρα", " ἀνήρ"),
        ("μοι", " ἐγώ"),
        ("πολύτροπον", "πολύτροπονος"),
        ("ὃς", "ὃς"),
        ("πολλὰ", "πολύς"),
        ("Τροίης", "Τροία"),
    ],
)
def test_grc_lemmatizer_lookup_assigns(grc_nlp, string, lemma):
    tokens = grc_nlp(string)
```

> ```
>   assert tokens[0].lemma_ == lemma
> ```

E       AssertionError: assert 'μοι' == ' ἐγώ'
E         -  ἐγώ
E         + μοι

test_grc.py:26: AssertionError
_ test_grc_lemmatizer_lookup_assigns[\u03c0\u03bf\u03bb\u03cd\u03c4\u03c1\u03bf\u03c0\u03bf\u03bd-\u03c0\u03bf\u03bb\u03cd\u03c4\u03c1\u03bf\u03c0\u03bf\u03bd\u03bf\u03c2] _

I get similar errors for all 5 lemmas I wrote into the test file. Could this  be an error related to unicode? Maybe the Greek polytonic characters are missing from spacy character definition? I suspect this because ancient use diacritics that may not be supported by spacy. Or is this error rather pointing to a problem with my lemma table?

Thanks.

Jacobo

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a unicode problem. Did you add the entry points in `setup.cfg` and `spacy_lookups_data/__init__.py` and reinstall the `spacy-lookups-data` package?

Comment: I did add the entry points in both files.  Could this be a problem then with the lemma file? I noticed that my json file does not validate because it has many "duplicates", which are in fact homonyms. But I saw that other lemma files do not have this issue.  If this is a problem, how do I deal with the homonyms?

Comment: The lookup tables are extremely simple. You can only have one lemma per token, so if a token is ambiguous you have to pick one lemma to provide. If you want anything more sophisticated you'd need to use the rule-based lemmatizer or your own custom lemmatizer. Check that your tables are valid JSON (you can load the file with `srsly.read_json()`) and rerun `pip install .` for the package?